# bclogo package with Miktex

Tags: miktex, bclogo

Good Evening

I've installed the bclogo package. And I'v got a problem I can't solve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.mps}{eps}{*}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!30]{}
$\bcdanger$
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

And below the result, as you can see, there isn't any logo. May you help me, please?

[image]

Comment: Remove the `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.mps}{eps}{*}{}`,

Comment: ... and welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: I have got an error : Package pdftex.def Error: Cannot convert bc-fleur.mps from MPS to PDF.
(pdftex.def)

Comment: and that : The support file `supp-pdf.mkii' (supp-pdf.tex) is 
missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you compile with pdflatex it works if you remove the `\DeclareGraphicsRule{.mps}{eps}{*}{}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[couleur=blue!30]{}
$\bcdanger$
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compile with pdf latex but I have got an error when I launch the compilation

Comment: `supp-pdf.mkii` is in the miktex package "mptopdf". Install it with the package manager.